# How to automate a TextField ExtJs? C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, extjs

This is html code, id is dynamic.

```
<td id="ext-gen2730" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1246 x-grid-cell-last g-cell-edit x-grid-cell-selected">
<div id="ext-gen2726" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left ! important;">&nbps</div>
```

my code

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//tbody/tr/td[4]/div")] 
 private IWebElement NroInscripcion;
 NroInscripcion.Click();` // this work
 NroInscripcion.SendKeys("20"); // not work -> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`
```

also i tried to

```
var action = new Actions();
action.SendKeys("21"); //not work
action.Clik(NroInscripcion).SendKeys("21"); //not work
```

Comment: Is this div works as textbox??

Answer (score 1):

You can only use sendKeys for an input html element. Not a div, span etc.

Do you have a textbox or textarea inside the div? If so search for that webelement and then use sendkeys

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found that the textarea had a name = 'name'. So I can use send keys. Thank you again.